# How to download files in customized location using Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I want to download a txt and pdf files to a specific folder. But it just downloads them on another folder. The website http://demo.automationtesting.in/FileDownload.html. Is there something wrong with the code or I didn't put the correct location of the folder?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions=Options()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_dictionary": "C:\DownloadedAutomationFiles"})

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver", chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/FileDownload.html")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_id("textbox").send_keys("testing")
driver.find_element_by_id("createTxt").click()   #generate file button
driver.find_element_by_id("link-to-download").click()    #dowload link


#Download PDF FILE

driver.find_element_by_id("pdfbox").send_keys("testing download text file")
driver.find_element_by_id("createPdf").click()   #generate file button
driver.find_element_by_id("pdf-link-to-download").click()    #dowload link

time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To download the required file within [Automation Demo Site](http://demo.automationtesting.in/FileDownload.html) to a specific folder using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) you need to pass the preference `"download.default_directory"` along with the value (location of the directory) through *`add_experimental_option()`* and you can use the following solution:

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Data_Files\output_files"
  })
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/FileDownload.html")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Download"))))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "textbox"))).send_keys("testing")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "createTxt"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "link-to-download"))).click()
```

Snapshot:

[image: chrome_download]

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Comment: how to say rewrite existing file?

Comment: I have to also use `"download.directory_upgrade": True` for the directory to actually change. Probably you want `"download.prompt_for_download": False` also.