# Is there any way to set a different location for Browser Downloads with Selenium on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, path, download

Normally, when downloading anything from a page on `Chrome Browser` it is prompted a download dialog with the Downloads location usually set at `C:\Users\YourUser\Downloads` by default.

[image]

So, I wanted to know if there's a way of modifying this particular path with some lines of code on Python (using Selenium module) rather than doing so manually. If so, what lines of code would work?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159116/7429447) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61998139/7429447) discussion helps you?

Comment: Indeed, the first link was the answer I was looking for, thanks master @undetectedSelenium