# selenium 4.13 python unable to change default download directory

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I feel like I'm in a viscous cycle of fixing one thing and breaking another. I've recently upgraded to Selenium 4.13 to take advantage of Selenium Manager's auto chromedriver feature. I think I finally have it installed correctly, but now I cannot change my default download directory no matter what I try. I've read through many examples and tried them all and the downloads just keep loading to the original default directory. Below is my setup, can anybody spot where I may be going wrong? I don't know if I'm having default "slash issues" or something, but I've tried several variations of c:\dev, c:\dev, and c:\\dev -- none of them seem to have any affect.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import date

import os
import re
import time
import logging

# begin copy

#user ID and Pwd to access the web site
download_path = "c:\dev"

# Set download folder
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
config = {"download.default_directory" : download_path}
op.add_experimental_option("prefs", config)
op.headless = False

##Call Chrome Browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.kyote.org/mc/login.aspx?url=kplacementMgmt.aspx")

#end copy
```

Comment: You are certainly not escaping backslashes in your path so that will not work. Follow examples as seen here: [how-to-change-download-directory-location-path-in-selenium-using-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716460/how-to-change-download-directory-location-path-in-selenium-using-chrome) I don't see what this has to do with Selenium Manager. Also pay attention to the answer and comments in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70159116/1467914

Comment: missing to add option to `Chrome()`, try this `browser= webdriver.Chrome(options=op)` that is reason your experimental are not working.

Comment: Thanks to both of you what you stated were my issues. That's part of the reason I'm in this mess is I keep thinking Selenium Manager and the newer versions of Selenium that auto-download/manage  ChromeDriver are one in the same, and I keep mixing the two code methods together :(